# When do we need to prefix delegate with "static"?

Tags: c#

I don't know when I should prefix my delegate with 'static' modifier?

I think without 'static', the delegate still works for general case.

Correct if I am wrong.

Give me examples in which the static delegate is a must.

EDIT 1: I made a mistake by assuming we can define a static delegate, for example,

```
static delegate void foo(int bar);
```

I closed this question because it is not possible to create static delegate :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate types cannot be declared with the `static` modifier.

Delegate fields, properties, and events may be declared static.  Like any other class member, this makes it a member of the class and not of instances of the class, so the field/property/event will be effectively global.

You only need this when you intend to share a member between all instances of the same class, instead of giving each instance its own copy of the member.

Comment: Delegate types mean global delegates as opposed to delegates defined within other types (struct or class)? I am confused with the terminologies.

Comment: A delegate type means the definition of a delegate.  (Like `public delegate void Foo(string bar);`)  No matter where these declarations occur, they cannot be static, just like nested types cannot be static.  (Ok, nested classes can actually be static, but *that means something different entirely.*  `static class A` means the same thing as `sealed abstract class A`, which is not the same meaning as the application of `static` to members.)

Comment: OK. You answer is good! Thanks. I made a mistake by assuming we can define a static delegate that I haven't tried to compile in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When all instances are going to call the same delegate.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. It is impossible to define static delegate. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: upvote because you might assume I am talking about delegate instance rather than delegate type.

Comment: Before edit it sounds like you are talking about delegate instance and in my answer you see the word `call`.  +1 for honesty.